# Vue3 lazy-loading view from another view?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible to lazy-load a view from another? For example if the user is on /auth, while the user fills out some inputs it should lazy-load the Fillout component and when user is done push the route to Fillout from Auth.

This is a bit of a stretch since I haven't found anything on this in the docs. It would make sense to me that something like this should exist since using chunks loads all at once? Am I looking at this wrong?

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/fillout',
    name: 'Fillout',
    component: () => import('../views/Fillout.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'Auth',
    component: () => import('../views/Auth.vue')
  }
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can split both routes into one chunk using named chunks: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk

Comment: Thank you. I know of components groups. But doesn't it then just load both of them at once?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. In that case I think you can call `import('yourComponent')` somewhere in your component? I haven't tried...

Comment: Np. I'm trying to pre-load a view from a view, not a component

Comment: A view is nothing but a component. It's just a convention to separate concerns. A "view" is just a component that will be used in Vue Router. About the solution, I just tested and it works. Just, expose a method to preload your "view" in your setup method. `const prefetch = () => import('../views/Auth')`, and call that method when you consider. You'll see in the network tab that the chunk is fetched and when you navigate to Auth it won't be fetched anymore as the "view" is already fetched.

Comment: Ah okay, that's pretty neat, can pre-fetch anything I want like that. Thank you very much Jose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, just write a method in your component to prefetch the component you want to lazy load.

```
const prefetch = () => import('@/path/to/MyComponent');
```

And then call that method when you consider, i.e., when the user has filled some mandatory inputs or the form is valid, ...

This method call will cause an HTTP request to load the necessary chunks, so, when you navigate to the desired route, the component is actually fetched, and no additional HTTP requests are done.